# Communication between Outlook and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, outlook, smtp, pop3

I have a simple question:

I want to develop some kind of C# application that can store data (outgoing and incoming messages) in SQL Server.

The goal is :

1. Retrieve data from SQL Server through Outlook or another client interface
2. Send e-mails from Outlook to SQL Server

Is there any proposition?

Thanks lot

Comment: The proposition is to post this on http://oDesk.com

Comment: There is not a lot to go on here. Please refer to this article for some ideas about how to revise your question. [Getting good answers on StackOverflow](http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/28/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-1-of-n/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456380/A-Csharp-SMTP-server-receiver)

Basing on this solution to create SMTP server, every message sent from outlook can be retrived by SMTP server and stored into database.

Now I am investigating how to do the same with pop3 server (create pop3 server linked with sql database)

Thanks